Sping Boot: Configuring additional beans of given type and arbitrary number
I have an application with a component that accepts a List<T> as a dependency. Several instances are already configured using sterotype annotations (@Component, etc.), and I'd like to add to that list an arbitrary number of T based on certain configuration properties.
I tried this approach, but with no luck:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootSandboxApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public interface T {
        default void printClassName() {
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    static class A implements T {}
    static class B implements T {}
    static class C implements T {}
    static class D implements T {}

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        // Presume these to be defined elsewhere in code
        @Bean public A a() { return new A(); }
        @Bean public B b() { return new B(); }

        // This does not add to the List<T> injected in the 
        // constructor of SpringBootSandboxApplication. 
        // Assume this accepts configuration properties to 
        // define the beans and that the number defined is 
        // arbitrary.
        @Bean public List<T> others() { return List.of(new C(), new D()); }
    }

    // I do not control how the dependent component recieves its Ts.
    @Autowired private List<T> ts;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSandboxApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        ts.forEach(T::printClassName);
    }

}

I'm expecting
A 
B 
C 
D

or any ordering thereof. But only the two beans directly configured are present:
A
B

What approach should I take where I cannot control the fact that A and B are configured outside my code base nor how the dependent component recieves its Ts?
